# JavaScript How Can I achive this in delete dialog

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

OK So I have view with data in table and i made delete option like in this tutorial

http://ricardocovo.com/2010/09/02/asp-mvc-delete-confirmation-with-ajax-jquery-ui-dialog/

But Now I have a question How Can I get a Name from the correct line to write something like this

Do you really want to delete "Product Name"

Comment: check this OnClientClick=“return confirm('Are you sure you want delete');”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think he asked about ASP.NET MVC, not Web forms, so the code will be as below

The view will be

```
<table id="table">
<tr>
   <td>Id</td>
   <td>Name</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
@foreach(var item in Mode.Items) {
<tr>
   <td>@item.Id</td>
   <td>@item.Name</td>
   <td><button class="deleted-link" value="Delete">delete</button></td>
</tr>
}    
</table>
<div id="delete-dialog" title="Confirmation">

</div>
```

and the Jquery script on the view should be

```
$(function(){   
       //alert($('.deleted-link'));
    $('.deleted-link').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(data){            
            var id = $(this).parent().parent().find('td :first').html();
            $('#delete-dialog').html('<p>Are you sure you want to delete the item with id = {' + id + '} ?</p>');
            $('#delete-dialog').dialog('open');
        });
    });

    $('#delete-dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false, width: 400, resizable: false, modal: true, //Dialog options
        buttons: {
            "Continue": function () {          
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

You can see the code example at http://jsfiddle.net/SVgEL/

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some thing Like this

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        ImageButton imb = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("deleteButton");

        string recordName = e.Row.Cells[3].Text;

        imb.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are You sure Want to Delete the record:-  "+ recordName.ToUpper()+" ? ');";
    }
}
```

Normal click Event with **button**

```
 <a href="url_to_delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want to delere');">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Is there an option without GridView ?

Comment: This answer is for WebForms. I believe that OP is using ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: then you need to Hook Up the Event in Client Side,  <a href="url_to_delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want to dele');">Delete</a>

Comment: It is actually not a Web form, guy.

Answer (score 0):

What about passing the model to the view and displaying the name?
Cant add comments, sorry for posting here in answers space.
If you dont want to pass the model you can always just pass the name as a parameter to the delete function from the table view.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are already using jQuery, check this out:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function removeCar(theLink) {
        var theTR = $(theLink).parents('tr');
        var model = $(theTR).children('td._model').html();

        var theConfirm = confirm("Are you sure you want to remove " + model + "?");
        if (theConfirm == true)
            $(theTR).remove();
    }
</script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Make</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Audi</td>
            <td class="_model">A3</td>
            <td><a href="#" onclick="removeCar(this); return false;">Remove</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Audi</td>
            <td class="_model">A4</td>
            <td><a href="#" onclick="removeCar(this); return false;">Remove</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Audi</td>
            <td class="_model">A5</td>
            <td><a href="#" onclick="removeCar(this); return false;">Remove</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```